# How would I delete an object in an array based on if there are more than one object with the same property?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. Each object in the array has the property `recipeID`. I'm looking to delete an object if its `recipeID` property matches another object's `recipeID` property.

Basically, I would like to perform a `array_unique()` on the array of objects but using the `$object->recipeID` as criterion that is being checked against.

For example, why wouldn't this work?

```
array_unique($objectArray);
```

If the `recipeID` property in two objects were the same, wouldn't that make those two objects equal? Assuming there were no other properties. Then `array_unique()` would see a multiple and delete one of them.

Comment: Please add some code as a minimum (non)working example.

Comment: To directly answer your question, from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/function.array-unique.php) ~ *"**Note:** Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 i.e. when the string representation is the same, the first element will be used."*

Comment: @pyStarter That exactly what I was looking for....I didn't find that when I searched. Thank you!